# How to pronounce 名 in 男性名 and 男性の名?

Tags: kanji, readings

男性名 is supposed to be read だんせいめい.

But according to [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/216457/meaning/m0u/)

> ［接尾］助数詞。人数を数えるのに用いる。「40名」［接尾］助数詞。人数を数えるのに用いる。「40名」

Obviously, it is not a 助数詞 here.

[な【名】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162179/meaning/m0u/%E5%90%8D/)has the following meaning:

> 一般に、その事物の呼び方。「人と名の付く生き物」「花の名」

めい【名】 also has the following meaning:

> なまえ。な。「姓と名」

So should 男性の名 be read だんせいのな or だんせいのめい?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

男性名 is read だんせいめい, 男性の名 is read だんせいのな.

As a generic suffix meaning "～ name", 名 is always めい, even though it's not used as a counter:

- 化合物名 かごうぶつめい "chemical compound name"
- 企業名 きぎょうめい "company name"
- プロジェクト名 プロジェクトめい "project name"
- OS名 オーエスめい "OS name"

This holds true for most fixed two-kanji compounds like 地名 ("place name") and 病名 ("disease name").

As a standalone noun, 名 is usually な:

- 君の名は きみのなは [*Your Name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Name)

... except in the case where 名 is used as opposed to 姓【せい】:

- 姓【せい】と名【めい】を記入してください。
  Write your family and first names.

Note that standalone 名【な】 is literary. 名前【なまえ】 is preferred in daily conversations.